# Quantum mechanics: total orthonormal sets & position/momentum space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Consider the position and momentum vector sets

$$X= \{|x\rangle |\ x \in \Bbb R^3\}$$

$$P= \{|p\rangle |\ p \in \Bbb R^3\}$$

By the assumption of quantum mechanics, both $X$ and $P$ are total orthonormal sets. In addition to that, $\langle x|p\rangle = e^{ip \cdot x} \neq 0$, but this conflicts with  Kreyszig's functional analysis Lemma 3.5-3 which states: a vector in an inner product space can only has countably many non-zero Fourier coefficients with respect to an orthonormal family.

How's this possible?

Is the position/momentum vector representation in quantum mechanics incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

An arbitrary basis $\{v_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}\subset \mathscr H$ may be uncountable, but $S=\{\alpha\in A:h\in \mathscr H;\  \langle h,v_\alpha\rangle \neq 0 \}$ is countable, and in this case, $h=\sum_{\alpha\in S}\langle h,v_\alpha\rangle v_\alpha. $

I am not a physicist, but isn't this fact exactly why $p$ and $x$ are quantized?

Comment: But S in my case is uncountable since both $X$ and $P$ are uncountable and their mutual product are all non zero

Comment: If you are working in a Hilbert Space, $S$ can not be uncountable.  There is a good introduction to these ideas in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: Then how can you explain the inner product of $|p>$ and $|x>$

Comment: Please define 1). the Hilbert Space you are working in. 2). The inner product you are using

Comment: Consider the $L^2(R)$ space and vector $|x>$ is eigen vector of $x$ operator, and |p> is eigen vector of $-i\partial_x$ operators with their inner product $<x|p> = e^{ip \cdot x}$

Comment: OK, I see now. Note that $<x|p>$ are $not$ Fourier coefficients. Rather, pick a countable orthonormal basis $(\psi_n)$ for your space (there are many such--e.g.a Gabor basis). Then, for $any$ vector $f$, in $\mathscr H$, its Fourier coefficients are $\langle f,\psi_n\rangle.$ In fact, expanding $<x|p>$ , you get (using Parseval) what I believe physicists call elements of a density matrix?

Comment: physicists like to express a vector like this $| \psi > = \int dx \psi(x) |x>$, I dont think that's a mathematical sound notation as it implies uncountable sum of basis,and they like to express $|x> = \int dp e^{ip \cdot x} |p>$ which confuses me